# Remove community boxes in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have created a simple minimum spanning tree and now have a data frame with columns 'from', 'to' and 'distance'.

Based on this, I found communities using the Louvain method, which I plotted. As far as I understand it, for clustering and plotting I need only the columns from and to, and the distance is not used.

How can I keep the communities I found, ideally each in a different color, but remove the box around the communities?

[image]

```
library(igraph)
from <- c(14, 25, 18, 19, 29, 23, 24, 36, 5, 22, 21, 29, 18, 26, 2, 45, 8, 7, 36, 42, 3, 23, 13, 13, 20, 15, 13, 7, 28, 9, 6, 37, 8, 4, 15, 27, 10, 2, 39, 1, 43, 21, 14, 4, 14, 8, 9, 40, 31, 1)
to <- c(16, 26, 27, 20, 32, 34, 35, 39, 6, 32, 35, 30, 22, 28, 45, 46, 48, 12, 38, 43, 42, 24, 27, 25, 30, 20, 50, 29, 34, 49, 40, 39, 11, 41, 46, 47, 50, 16, 46, 40, 44, 31, 17, 40, 44, 23, 33, 42, 33, 1)
distance <- c(0.3177487, 0.3908324, 0.4804059, 0.4914682, 0.5610357, 0.6061082, 0.6357532, 0.6638961, 0.7269725, 0.8136463, 0.8605391, 0.8665838, 0.8755252, 0.8908454, 0.9411793, 0.9850834, 1.0641603, 1.0721154, 1.0790506, 1.1410964, 1.1925349, 1.2115428, 1.2165045, 1.2359032, 1.2580204, 1.2725243, 1.2843610, 1.2906908, 1.3070725, 1.3397053, 1.3598817, 1.3690732, 1.3744088, 1.3972220, 1.4472312, 1.4574936, 1.4654772, 1.4689660, 1.5999424, 1.6014316, 1.6305410, 1.6450413, 1.6929959, 1.7597620, 1.8113320, 2.0380866, 3.0789517, 4.0105981, 5.1212614, 0.0000000)
mst <- cbind.data.frame(from, to, distance)

g <- graph.data.frame(mst[, 1:2], directed = FALSE)
lou <- cluster_louvain(g)
set.seed(1)
plot(lou, g, vertex.label = NA, vertex.size=5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blobs around the groups can be turned off like this:

```
plot(lou, g, vertex.label = NA, vertex.size=5, mark.groups = NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?

```
plot(lou, g, vertex.label = NA, vertex.size = 5, mark.border = NA)
```

[image]